# Seeking SSH emulator that behaves as a terminal on the server side

Tags: ssh, server, emulation

I write code for embedded control systems and frequently use proprietary black-box modules to communicate with external devices. In my world, RS-232 connectivity is still commonplace. More and more devices, however, are joining the modern world and implementing various TCP and UDP options.

One such device runs an SSH server and interacts with an SSH client opened by the proprietary module. I have to develop code without the device. If this were RS-232, I could simply open a terminal connected to RS-232 and interact with the module, seeing what is sent and sending replies to observe the module's behaviour.

I'm looking for SSH and Telnet "servers" that would allow me to do the same for sessions on those protocols. So far, I've found SSH honeypots that allow me to see payloads from the client, but nothing that lets me send strings in return.

I suspect there's a solution out there, but I simply haven't the vocabulary to describe it. All clues welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you can post your question over on [sf] where system and network administrators help people.

Comment: Have done! Thanks for the tip - I'm clearly new here.